Are there ways to throttle HDD operations based on its temperature?
When I am replacing spare drives on my array I have to keep them outside of the case, and the lack of airflow and heavy workload shoots the temperature to around 55~60 C.
The drive spec says

Recommended maximum temperature   55°C (131°F)
Maximum temperature   62°C (143°F)

It's not the end of the world, but I would be fine if took twice the time (currently takes 2h) but didn't cross the 55 C mark. smartd even shows a warning over 55 C because it have those drivers in the database.
Are there any (convenient) way to throttle disk drivers based on the temperature?

How do you define convenient?  I don't have a RAID to play w/ and you didn't mention whether you're using a Linux software raid or a hardware one, so I have no idea what processes would be involved in doing this rebuild, but have a look at man ionice ... a simple loop (or even using watch, grep & ionice should allow you to achieve something useful if it's a software raid.

it's mdadm (md-raid) softraid. But i'm considering either lvm+raid or brtfs if that makes things easier.
